# AWSCognito Facebook Login Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, facebook-login, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use AWSCognito to sign in with a Facebook Access Token.

My identity pool is set up & I have the Facebook Access Token.

Unfortunately, the documentation is very limited for this.  Has anyone successfully got a Facebook user logged in with AWSCognito?

So far I have;

```
let provider: Dictionary = [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook : accessToken.authenticationToken]
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUWest2, identityPoolId: POOL_IDENTITY_STRING)
```

I'm assuming I need to pass-in the provider somewhere.

I tried to do this;

```
credentialProvider.identityProvider.logins() = provider
```

but I'm getting: "Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did something just like this recently.

You will want to init your credential provider using an identity provider manager.

```
credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: xxx, 
    identityPoolId: yyy, 
    identityProviderManager: idpm)
```

However, you can't just pass in the dictionary `["graph.facebook.com" : <access token>]` as the third parameter.

You need something that conforms to the AWSIdentityProviderManager protocol, which basically just returns a task returning a dictionary.

I ended up making a simple wrapper class for this, see below.

```
import AWSCognito
class myIdentityProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {

var keytokens: [String:String]?

init (logins: [String:String]) {
    keytokens = logins
}

func logins () -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {

    let task = AWSTask(result: keytokens as AnyObject?)
    return task as! AWSTask<NSDictionary>
}

}
```

So, then your code would be rewritten:

```
let provider: Dictionary = [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook : accessToken.authenticationToken]
let idpm = myIdentityProvider(provider)
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: .EUWest2, 
    identityPoolId: POOL_IDENTITY_STRING, 
    identityProviderManager: idpm)
```